# NgOnInit undefined public variables

Tags: angular, three.js

I have public variables in Component that are associated with ThreeJs, I try to apply them in the ngOnInt method, but I get an error

Variables

```
export class CustomizerComponent implements OnInit {
  public threeJsVars: {
    scene: any;
    kitchen: any;
    camera: any;
    renderer: any;
    canvas: any;
    canvasSmall: any;
    controls: any;
    mouse: any;
    raycaster: any;
    selectedTexture: any;
    INTERSECTED: any;
    loader: any;
    BACKGROUND_COLOR: 0xffffff;
  };

 // ngOn Init()
}
```

NgOnInit Method

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Scene
    this.threeJsVars.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    console.log(this.threeJsVars.scene);
    this.threeJsVars.scene.background = new THREE.Color(
      this.threeJsVars.BACKGROUND_COLOR
    );
 }
```

Error:

```
core.mjs:6469 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'scene')
    at CustomizerComponent.ngOnInit (customizer.component.ts:54:27)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2526:1)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2495:1)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2446:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9484:1)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10594:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9493:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10640:1)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9265:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9519:1)
```

Comment: You just defined a type there, not an object. You'd need public threeJsVars = {}

Comment: Your public property is only declared, not initialized; the default value for uninitialized properties is indeed `undefined`. The first line inside `ngOnInit` can be `this.threeJsVars = {} as any;` to give it an initial value. You can also do this inline, after you declare the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You just defined how the threeJsVars looks like but did not initialize it.

You should first define an interface for ThreeJsVars outside of CustomizerComponent:

```
interface ThreeJsVars: {
  scene: any;
  kitchen: any;
  camera: any;
  renderer: any;
  canvas: any;
  canvasSmall: any;
  controls: any;
  mouse: any;
  raycaster: any;
  selectedTexture: any;
  INTERSECTED: any;
  loader: any;
}
```

then you initialize the variable inside CustomizerComponent:

```
public threeJsVars: ThreeJsVars = {} as ThreeJsVars;
```

Comment: I suspect this (threeJsVars: ThreeJsVars = {}) will give you a lot of errors ;-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).